# hadoop tmp directory does not space (No space left on device tmp directory)

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

While running the sqoop commands, it runs the java codes and stores them into the `/tmp` directory so, it is giving me the following error:

> (Could not create temporary directory:
>   /tmp/sqoop-varunrit/compile/12a0219dee9fe0f53273687704042e4d; check
>   for a directory permissions issue on /tmp.)

I have checked the permissions of `/tmp` directory it is(1777).
I have also forcefully tried to create floder to `/tmp` but its giving me error that not enough space.

can i change the current /tmp location or any other solution that can help me.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand these parameters:

**bindir**

The import process compiles the source into `.class` and `.jar` files; these are ordinarily stored under `/tmp`. You can select an alternate target directory with `--bindir`. For example, `--bindir /scratch`.

**outdir**

The `.java` source file for your class will be written to the current working directory when you run sqoop. You can control the output directory with `--outdir`. For example, `--outdir src/generated/`.

---

Use `--bindir <new-directory>`  in your sqoop command.